# Javascript code not correctly summing number using Google Apps with HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a JavaScript in Google Apps that will write monthly dollars to a spreadsheet from an HTML user input.

It functions where it take input from the user via html input. I then use a Class that captures and calculates as the user is entering content, which is actively writing to the screen.

It needs to take in positive and negative numbers. While it takes the input of the user, it only displays the number as a positive amount, even when it is a negative. In addition, it is not calculating correctly. I noticed that if the number has a comma, for example 1,000, it drops everything after the comma. I am sharing below the header script and then script in the body of the HTML file as well as the html code with the function. Lastly, I am using Bootstrap which functions fine for other areas of the code.

Head script

```js
<script>
 
  function toFinalNumberFormat(controlToCheck) {
    var enteredNum = '' + controlToCheck.value;
    enteredNum = enteredNum.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ''); 
    controlToCheck.value = Number(enteredNum).toLocaleString();
  }
</script>
```

Script in HTML body

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("add-input").addEventListener("input", sumTotal);  //listener when numbers are inputted into monthly spend fields

 function sumTotal ()  {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('add-input')

    var totalSum = 0

    for ( let i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      totalSum += parseFloat(inputs[i].value || 0, 10)
    }
     var total = document.getElementById("total");
     total.value = totalSum.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
      
  }
```

This is the HTML snippet

```html
<h5>Monthly Spend</h5>
 <div class="container3">
   <div class = "row">
      <div class="form-floating col-sm-2"> 
        <input type="text" id="jan" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="January" onblur="toFinalNumberFormat(this);" oninput="sumTotal()" placeholder="0.00">
        <label for="jan">January<br>$</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-floating col-sm-2"> 
        <input type="text" id="feb" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="February" onblur="toFinalNumberFormat(this);" oninput="sumTotal()" placeholder="0.00">
        <label for="feb">February<br>$</label>
      </div>

       <div class="form-floating col-sm-2"> 
        <input type="text" id="mar" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="March" onblur="toFinalNumberFormat(this);" oninput="sumTotal()" placeholder="0.00">
        <label for="mar">March<br>$</label>
      </div>

     <div class="form-floating col-sm-2"> 
        <input type="text" id="apr" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="April" onblur="toFinalNumberFormat(this);" oninput="sumTotal()" placeholder="0.00">
        <label for="apr">April<br>$</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-floating col-sm-2"> 
        <input type="text" id="may" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="May" onblur="toFinalNumberFormat(this);" oninput="sumTotal()" placeholder="0.00">
        <label for="may">May<br>$</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-floating col-sm-2"> 
        <input type="text" id="jun" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="June" onblur="toFinalNumberFormat(this);" oninput="sumTotal()" placeholder="0.00">
        <label for="jun">June<br>$</label>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class = "row">
      <div class="form-floating col-sm-2"> 
        <input type="text" id="jul" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="July" onblur="toFinalNumberFormat(this);" oninput="sumTotal()" placeholder="0.00">
        <label for="jul">July<br>$</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-floating col-sm-2"> 
        <input type="text" id="aug" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="August" onblur="toFinalNumberFormat(this);" oninput="sumTotal()" placeholder="0.00">
        <label for="aug">August<br>$</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-floating col-sm-2"> 
        <input type="text" id="sep" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="September" onblur="toFinalNumberFormat(this);" oninput="sumTotal()" placeholder="0.00">
        <label for="sep">September<br>$</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-floating col-sm-2"> 
        <input type="text" id="oct" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="October" onblur="toFinalNumberFormat(this);" oninput="sumTotal()" placeholder="$0.00">
        <label for="oct">October<br>$</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-floating col-sm-2"> 
        <input type="text" id="nov" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="November" onblur="toFinalNumberFormat(this);" oninput="sumTotal()" placeholder="0.00">
        <label for="nov">November<br>$</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-floating col-sm-2"> 
        <input type="text" id="dec" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="December" onblur="toFinalNumberFormat(this);" oninput="sumTotal()" placeholder="0.00">
        <label for="dec">December<br>$</label>
      </div>
</div>
  <div class = "row">
     
    <div class="form-floating col-sm-4"> 
        <h3>Total:  $<output type="number" id="total"></output></h3>
        
      </div>
```

Can someone please point out what is wrong with the code? Thanks!

Comment: FYI, `parseFloat()` only takes one argument. The radix argument is only available in `parseInt()` (and it defaults to 10, so it's usually not needed).

Comment: You only call `toFinalNumberFormat()` when the user leaves the field, but you call `sumTotal()` as they're typing. You need to remove the commas in `sumTotal()`.

Comment: @Barmar  Ok, I need the 'parseFloat()' because users will enter values involving decimal numbers since they are not necessarily whole numbers all the time.

Comment: You need to use `parseFloat(inputs[i].value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''))`

Comment: You're removing the `.` in your regexp, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Sorry can you please clarify, I'm new to javascript. I updated the code to have it read as you did above but now it is not calculating at all. I'm getting the NaN value in the field that is displaying the screen. Let me update my question to show the full html, I realized I left out the output field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a list of elements, you need to iterate over it to add all the event listeners.

You need to remove the commas calling `parseFloat()` on each value in the loop, not after you calculate the total, because `parseFloat()` can't parse numbers with comma separators.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".add-input").forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener("input", sumTotal);
  input.addEventListener("blur", () => toFinalNumberFormat(input));
});

function sumTotal() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('add-input');

  var totalSum = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    totalSum += parseFloat(inputs[i].value.replace(/[^-\d.]/g, '') || 0);
  }
  var total = document.getElementById("total");
  total.value = totalSum.toFixed(2);
}

function toFinalNumberFormat(controlToCheck) {
  var enteredNum = '' + controlToCheck.value;
  enteredNum = enteredNum.replace(/[^-\d.]/g, '');
  controlToCheck.value = Number(enteredNum).toLocaleString();
}
```

```html
<h5>Monthly Spend</h5>
<div class="container3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-floating col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="jan" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="January" placeholder="0.00">
      <label for="jan">January<br>$</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="feb" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="February" placeholder="0.00">
      <label for="feb">February<br>$</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="mar" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="March" placeholder="0.00">
      <label for="mar">March<br>$</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="apr" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="April" placeholder="0.00">
      <label for="apr">April<br>$</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="may" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="May" placeholder="0.00">
      <label for="may">May<br>$</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="jun" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="June" placeholder="0.00">
      <label for="jun">June<br>$</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-floating col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="jul" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="July" placeholder="0.00">
      <label for="jul">July<br>$</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="aug" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="August" placeholder="0.00">
      <label for="aug">August<br>$</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="sep" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="September" placeholder="0.00">
      <label for="sep">September<br>$</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="oct" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="October" placeholder="$0.00">
      <label for="oct">October<br>$</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="nov" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="November" placeholder="0.00">
      <label for="nov">November<br>$</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="dec" class="form-control input-group add-input" aria-placeholder="December" placeholder="0.00">
      <label for="dec">December<br>$</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="form-floating col-sm-4">
      <h3>Total: $<output type="number" id="total"></output></h3>

    </div>
```

Comment: Would you want to check `totalSum` before writing it to the input? I don't understand the requirement above: _...it only displays the number as a positive amount, even when it is a negative._, but this would allow negative numbers correct? Perhaps the OP wants them wrapped in parenthesis like negative numbers in account?

Comment: If the user enters a negative number, the `-` will be removed by the `replace()` call, so the result can never be negative.

Comment: @Barmar what is interesting is that the code is working but the total remains not showing the addition until all 12 fields are filled out, it then will show the total. I had updated the html input and added value= "0" but that doesn't work. 

Also I need each input to show -5,000 and also deduct that from the total. So if I enter in -5,000 in the January field, my total should start off with -5,000. I need to allow the user to enter in -5,000.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Change the regexp to `/[^-\d.]/g` to allow negative numbers.

Comment: I forgot the second argument to `replace()`, I've fixed it.

Comment: @Barmar I updated the regexp and included the - and it allows user to enter but as soon as you leave the field, it converts it to positive and does the same with the total

Comment: You need to fix the regexp in `toFinalNumberFormat()` the same way I fixed it here.

Comment: @Barmar I updated in both places and while it lets me enter a negative number, it converts it a positive and total only recognizes it as a positive number.

Comment: I've put the complete solution in my answer. It works correctly.

Comment: @Barmar thanks! It works! I am going to compare what you gave me to what I did so I can learn. Thank you so much!